# Pinterest API - How to create V3 or V4 application (Not v5 Beta)

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, pinterest

I'm trying to use Pinterest API for building connector,
In the API documentation URLs are using v3
See: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/#operation/ads_v3_get_advertisers_by_owner_user_id_handler_GET

But when I create application it is V5 (Beta)
Can't find how to create V3/V4

In Postman after creating access-token (Passing OAuth 2 authentication)
If I send the GET request with v3 - I get "Authorization Failed"
and using v5 - I get "message": "API method not found."

Or - How to read same data using V5 apis?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently V3/V4 api are deprecated - can't get new access to it
According to response from their support

I spent quite some time that would have been saved if it was mentioned in relevant places like the v3 documentation page